# Do i need to use stacking of activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a problem here, and I don't know why how this happen.

```
activity A - login
activity B - list
activity C - profile

1. I have an activity A, B and C.
2. From activity A, I can open activity B.
3. From activity B, i can open activity C.
4. When I press the back from activity C, it goes back to activity A and I want it to be in activity B.
```

snippet from activity C:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

snippet from activity B:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("Clicked item id", " "+ id); 
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChildProfile.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            }
```

snippet from activity A:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Children.class);
                      startActivity(i);
                      finish();
```

Comment: `finish()` closes the activity, so there's no more activity B to go back to.

Comment: Np, you may want to accept @Crazy's answer as it's more comprehensive and you know.. actually an answer as opposed to my comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when u Open the Activity C u are finishing Activity B

so just remove `finish()` from  Activity B class code. when u calling the Intent

for more information refer following link

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 1):

Add in `Activity C`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
           Intent i = new Intent(C.this, B.class);
            startActivity(i);
          super.onBackPressed();
            }
```

Or remove `finish();`  in `Activity B`